# Getting "Error executing SQL statement" while calling MySQL procedure from JasperReports

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jasper-reports

Iam trying to call procedure from jasper reports but I'm getting this error

```
sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error executing SQL statement for : ReportTemplate
```

Although procedure is working fine in when I'm calling it from *mysql*. This is the way i hve call procedure from *JasperReports*

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="ReportTemplate" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c01724b6-8aeb-4f3e-9c46-00fab3c0b602">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="param1" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
<![CDATA[Call Student_fee_report ($P{param1})]]>
</queryString>
<field name="FeeType" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Fee_Head_Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Amount" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Expected_Month_Year" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="sub" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="Status" class="java.lang.String"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
    <band height="56" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="aed283f1-6b6d-4eb4-94df-7ce177ff85d1" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="46"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font size="22" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Student Fee Detail]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="13" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="71f2d5cb-dcfa-46fc-ab1f-a1c07eb7a8f2" x="50" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Fee Type]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="975fc716-7a73-493b-ad25-9bd16650fb8a" x="140" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Fee Name]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="2dd37133-d509-4b77-a40c-ec62a180862c" x="230" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Amount]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="0ed8adcd-6b05-4212-aff1-a4f8528aa301" x="330" y="0" width="110" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Expected Date]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="314552a3-3e73-454d-acbc-8b6f186f997a" x="440" y="0" width="110" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Submission Date]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement uuid="b1d93a9a-3f19-4eba-a877-a4ccc64f2e90" x="10" y="0" width="27" height="20"/>
            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Status]]></text>
        </staticText>
    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="4ee795b7-b55b-470d-ba6d-3679dc631f3c" x="50" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FeeType}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="ae6209b5-5211-4ec4-bbc6-493260acb2f3" x="140" y="0" width="90" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Fee_Head_Name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="5df479c0-c886-44ac-9f38-8e29558b3cff" x="230" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="82c52ca4-63de-43c4-9117-f20de45e0615" x="330" y="0" width="110" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Expected_Month_Year}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="e78448c2-b25e-4351-b078-56c62aa43570" x="440" y="0" width="110" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{sub}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement uuid="52b24bc7-382c-4408-b957-6d6dd1fea00c" x="10" y="0" width="27" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Status}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="23" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
    </jasperReport>
```

Comment: Could you share the procedure code? otherwise this the only way to call procedure from JR server.

Comment: thnx for rply ok im going to put down xml code.